# Test paypal in sandbox, making a paypal (not credit card) payment from an account with no credit

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I would like to test what happens when a payment is made from an account with no credit. I am using the paypal payment method; not a credit card payment.

The [advice I have found](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/) suggests changing the amount value to 107.55 
and activate the Negative Testing in my sandbox account, but that is only working with credit card payment methods.

Is there a way to handle the equivalent error with paypal payment method?

Comment: I have reworded your question a little to make it more readable. Remember that you can always [edit] your question again to improve it, and this is encouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank u Vince that's really nice of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can negative test PayPal Express checkout amount error's; here is a doc on error testing this: [enter link description here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/?mark=negative%20testing)

Now as far as account related errors you cannot negative test if that's what your looking for as [shown in this doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)